# iOS 6 update problem: how to switch to Indian store?

Tags: ipad, ios

I just updated my iPad 2 to to iOS 6 yesterday. Today when I tried to buy an app the usual way from the App Store, I got the message "Your account is not valid for use in US store. You must switch to the Indian store before purchasing." I am unable to update my old apps as well and am getting the same message. Any idea how I should switch to the Indian store?

Comment: Make sure you read up on the ramifications of switching countries for an account. It is one way and you lose past purchases if they are not allowed / sold in the new country. Most people maintain accounts for each region so that they can retain all past purchases but go forward buying things in the new region. Apple support can explain things to you if you are not clear on things...

Answer (score 10):

I too faced this problem after the iOS6 Upgrade. This worked for me:

1. Open the Appstore
2. Go to *Featured* (scroll down to bottom until you see your Apple ID)
3. Click on *Apple ID*
4. *View* Apple ID
5. Enter your Password
6. Once you login it will say your account is transferred to the respective country.

Hope this solves your problem with updates.

Comment: Did you enact a [change of the country of your entire account](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2443094?start=45&tstart=0) using [steps like this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1311) or just choose to shop a different country temporarily?

Comment: Thanks for this! I was offered to switch to the US store just to see an app that wasn't available in the Indian store and I was disappointed to see no straightforward way of switching back. Sad!

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is some issue or may be because of security this happens with iOS 6. So nothing, just press on Appstore under settings. Press down the button with your e-mail on and choose "view Apple Id". It will automatically switch your store.

Answer (score 2):

If this is still an issue after trying what's been suggested, then try signing out and sign in again using your existing Apple ID. It will automatically shift you to the relevant store. I also had similar problems after upgrading to iOS 6, but now it's working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Message told me your account is not valid in the Indian store you have to switch your account to the u.s store before purchasing.

Comment: the "how to switch" is exactly the question here...